# How to change default text in Laravel Spark PDF receipt?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I need to translate text on the PDF receipt like Invoice Number: Product: but can not find in the code where to do this. Please direct me the correct files.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Spark uses Cashier to generate the PDF invoices. After publishing the Cashier views, you can edit the `receipt.blade.php` file in `/resources/views/vendor/cashier`

Publish the Cashier views by running:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=cashier-views`

Comment: I am using the new version of Spark and it does not seem to be using cashier. There is no cashier folder in the vendor folder from which any views can be published.

Comment: Cashier is in the Laravel vendor directory